# MongoDB where clause

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have mongoDB "users" collection in JSON format and I want to return all the data having privacy is true. How can I do it ?

```
{

    "name" : "Maria Kari",
    "social" : [
        {
            "facebook" : "www.fb.com/maria.mongodb",
            "privacy" : true
        },
        {
            "twitter" : "www.tw.com/mongodb",
            "privacy" : false
        }
    ],
    "personal" : [
        {
            "cell_no" : "+1-99082198414",
            "privacy" : true
        },
        {
            "email" : "maria@mongodb.com",
            "privacy" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

Here, I want to return the data having privacy is true. For example, facebook, it has privacy is equal to true. How to build query for this ?

Thank You. :')

Comment: What r u want to return?Users?Users.social?Users.personal?

Comment: All the data. But privacy of social should be true and also for personal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773936/how-select-data-with-given-condition is it duplicate of this qn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.users.find( { 
    $or:[{ 'social.privacy': true },{'personal.privacy': true}] 
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much <3 I didn't know "social.privacy". Which website do you suggest me to learn queries ?

Comment: And what I have to do if I want to return only data having privacy equal to true ?

Comment: I learn query from official document.And some source code of third library,just like mongoose

Comment: Okay thanks! What about returning only data with privacy = true ?

Comment: The query in my answer is just return all users with privacy = true,what you want?