# How select data with given condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have following data.

```
{

    "name" : "Maria",
    "facebook" : [
        {
            "data" : "fb.com",
            "privacy" : true
        }
    ],
    "twitter" : [
        {
            "data" : "twitter.com",
            "privacy" : false
        }
    ],
    "google" : [
        {
            "data" : "google.com",
            "privacy" : true
        }
    ],
    "phno" : [
        {
            "data" : "+1-1289741824124",
            "privacy" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to return only data having privacy is equal to true. How do I do it ?

I tried but it returns all data having privacy is equal to false also. How do I query the data ?

Please post MongoDB query not Javascript code.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want each document where any of those fields contains a `privacy: true` element, or for every document like this you want to filter out non-privacy elements from each of those arrays? Also, what is the query you tried but didn't work as expected?

Comment: Exactly ! What I did is put the condition where privacy: true  but then it returned the data having privacy : false also. It should return all the data having privacy: true. Twitter has privacy: false so it wont be returned.

Comment: Do the subarrays expect to contain more than just one element each, and if so do you need to return every subarray item where the privacy matches i.e. do you expect for example several items to be contained in the facebook array if there are multiple matches there?

Comment: If you want JS code to do this: [`var keys = Object.keys(obj);
var result = {}; keys.forEach(function(key) { if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key][0].privacy === true) {result[key] = obj[key];}});
console.log(result);
`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/caLayh27/)

Comment: Amazing that there are 5 answers that all do pretty much the same thing and still miss the point of the question.

Comment: True! I have mentioned it "I tried but it returns all data having privacy is equal to false also. How do I query the data ?" Still people posting javascript code and that I already know it. Come on people. Using javascript is easy to implement. If we can do anything with javascript they would have not created queries. :/

Comment: "possible" duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37769629/mongodb-where-clause

Comment: @KaSh : Thank you for letting me know. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### edit

having structure like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575e4c8731dcfb59af388e1d"),
    "name" : "Maria",
    "providers" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "facebook",
            "data" : "fb.com",
            "privacy" : true
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "twitter",
            "data" : "twitter.com",
            "privacy" : false
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "google",
            "data" : "google.com",
            "privacy" : true
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "phno",
            "data" : "+1-1289741824124",
            "privacy" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

with query like this:

```
db.maria.aggregate([{
            $project : {
                _id : 1,
                name : 1,
                "providers" : {
                    $filter : {
                        input : "$providers",
                        as : "p",
                        cond : {
                            $eq : ["$$p.privacy", true]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
    ])
```

we are gaining dynamic output, and we don't need to take care about provider name as this is covered by generic structure

```
{
    "providers" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "facebook",
            "data" : "fb.com",
            "privacy" : true
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "google",
            "data" : "google.com",
            "privacy" : true
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "phno",
            "data" : "+1-1289741824124",
            "privacy" : true
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Maria"
}
```

### end of edit

The way you could get this is using aggregation framework.
As we have an array for each field, we need to unwind it first, then we can use `$project` to set field value or simply null. As this looks like a simple query, it could give a bit of trouble. The way we can improve that is change a document structure, to have an array of providers and simple providerType field.

Aggregation stages below:

```
db.maria.find()
var unwindFb = {
    $unwind : "$facebook"
}
var unwindtw = {
    $unwind : "$twitter"
}
var unwindgo = {
    $unwind : "$google"
}
var unwindph = {
    $unwind : "$phno"
}
var project = {
    $project : {
        _id : 1,
        name : 1, // list other fields here

        facebook : {
            $cond : {
                if  : {
                    $gte : ["$facebook.privacy", true]
                },
            then : [{
                    data : "$facebook.data",
                    privacy : "$facebook.privacy"
                }
            ],
            else  : null
        }
    },
    twitter : {
        $cond : {
            if  : {
                $gte : ["$twitter.privacy", true]
            },
        then : [{
                data : "$twitter.data",
                privacy : "$twitter.privacy"
            }
        ],
        else  : null
    }
},
google : {
    $cond : {
        if  : {
            $gte : ["$google.privacy", true]
        },
    then : [{
            data : "$google.data",
            privacy : "$google.privacy"
        }
    ],
    else  : null
}
},
phno : {
    $cond : {
        if  : {
            $gte : ["$phno.privacy", true]
        },
    then : [{
            data : "$phno.data",
            privacy : "$phno.privacy"
        }
    ],
    else  : null
}
}
}
}

db.maria.aggregate([unwindFb, unwindtw, unwindgo, unwindph, project])
```

then output looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575df49d31dcfb59af388e1a"),
    "name" : "Maria",
    "facebook" : [ 
        {
            "data" : "fb.com",
            "privacy" : true
        }
    ],
    "twitter" : null,
    "google" : [ 
        {
            "data" : "google.com",
            "privacy" : true
        }
    ],
    "phno" : [ 
        {
            "data" : "+1-1289741824124",
            "privacy" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate it worked. But when I have more accounts that is dynamically added at that time what should I do ?

Comment: @maria there is an easier way to do it will provide solution is on $filter  so there will be only one step in projection

Comment: @MariaKari please see new edit with `$filter`  requires mongo 3.2

Comment: The structure you have provided is more flexible. So I'm going to use that structure. Thank you so much for your efforts. <3

Answer (score -1):

If you are open to use lodash ...this is how you can do it...

```
    var tmp  = {
    ...you json here 
    }

    var res =[];//result array of filtered data
     _.forIn(tmp, function (o) {
                    if (Array.isArray(o)) {
                        if (o[0].privacy === true) {
                            res.push(o);
                        }
                    }
    });
```

Comment: OP is asking how to query the data, not filter after the fact.

Comment: well I guess OP should be more specific ..as there are 2 answers suggesting the similar solution ..and obviosly the question is not framed correctly ..

Comment: True, but the question was tagged with Mongo, so it's implied.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the below code to iterate the object and check for the privacy true

```
var list = {

"name" : "Maria",
"facebook" : [
    {
        "data" : "fb.com",
        "privacy" : true
    }
],
"twitter" : [
    {
        "data" : "twitter.com",
        "privacy" : false
    }
],
"google" : [
    {
        "data" : "google.com",
        "privacy" : true
    }
],
"phno" : [
    {
        "data" : "+1-1289741824124",
        "privacy" : true
    }
]
```

}

```
$.each(Object.keys(list), function(index,value){
  if(list[value][0].privacy)
  {
 console.log(list[value][0]);
 }
});
```

Comment: OP is asking how to query the data, not filter after the fact.